# Как получить список доступных разрешений экрана?

Tags: python, экран

Как в python получить список доступных разрешений на используемом мониторе, решение нужно кроссплатформенное.

Пока я смог получить только под linux решение.

```
from Xlib import X, display
from Xlib.ext import randr
d = display.Display()
s = d.screen()
windows = s.root.create_window(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, s.root_depth)
res = randr.get_screen_resources(windows)
for mode in res.modes:
    w, h = mode.width, mode.height
    print("{}.{}".format(w, h))
```

Comment: На английском SO толпа вариантов, пробуйте, какие вам подойдут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python

Comment: @CrazyElf да, я это уже видел, они все показывают минимальные и максимальные или уже именно уставноленное разрешение, а мне нужно, как в самой ос в настройках экрана, получить список доступных разрешений для монитора, а именно конкретный перечень.